# Resonance Circuit

Tags: resonance

In a lab exercise I am given the circuit below. I am asked to compare my experimental findings with the theoretical values. Although, my book only analyzes the parallel and series RLC Circuits. Therefore I tried to analyze it on my own. This is what I find. Do you think any of this is wrong? The only thing that baffles me is Q, which in resonance its value goes to infinity.

I find that resonance happens when

\$ ω= \frac{1}{\sqrt{LC}} \$

and then I try to study the curve of \$I(ω)\$

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Input impedance rise to infinity at resonance and if by this you want to define Q as infinity then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

At resonance \$\omega_0, \ \  X_L(\omega )=|X_c(\omega )|\$

and \$Q= \frac{R}{X_{ (\ L  \ or \ C \ \ \ } \ \ \ )(\omega _o)}\$

for \$R>{X(\omega _o)_{ (\ L  \ or \ C \ \ )} \ \ } \ \ \ \ Q>1 \$

This would be a notch filter with \$ Z=∞  \ \ at \ \ \omega _o \$  where the reactances are equal but opposite phase so they cancel the current.